# Building a for loop with two variables

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I'm trying to build a loop that iterates and places the variables lat and lng into , "target_coordinates". How do I format this correctly with two variables?

```
lat=hotel_df["Lat"]
lng=hotel_df["Lng"]
for i,j in lat,lng:
    target_coordinates = "{lat},{lng}"
    target_search = "Hotel"
    target_radius = 5000
```

I either get the error above or:
TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: What line of code does that error occur in? Post the entire error message including the traceback.

Comment: The error occurs in the for statement (for i,j in lat,lng:)

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].** What do/don't you understand from that error message, exactly? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to string, which is wrong and produces an error. To solve it, try to use this code:

```
for i, row in hotel_df.iterrows():
    lat, lng = row['Lat'], row['Lng']
    target_coordinates = f"{lat},{lng}"
    target_search = "Hotel"
    target_radius = 5000
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working but I get the following error:

Comment: ---> 23     hotel_name=places_data["results"][0]["name"]

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Don't use `iterrows()`, there are many better alternatives, like `itertuples()` or `to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip` and `values`:

```
...
for i,j in zip(lat.values, lng.values):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and I get "{i},{j}
{'html_attributions': [], 'results': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'}
{i},{j}
{'html_attributions': [], 'results': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'}"

Comment: This error cannot be raised by the shown code. You should ask a new question with the relevant code and the full stacktrace. As you have been said in comments, a good question always contains a [mcve] so make sure to give enough information for others to reproduce.